# Why does the MSE sklearn library give me a different squared error compared to the l2 norm squared error?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I was trying to compute the mean squared error as in:

[image]

in python. I saw that [scipt/sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-error) had an implementation for it already. However, when I tried comparing it to my own implementation they did *NOT* agree. Why is that? My implementation simply uses the norm 2 (or the Frobenius norm not matching) and nothing else fancy.

To test this I wrote the following script:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

X_truth = np.ones((5,6))
X_pred = 1.7*np.ones((5,6))

print 'LA error: ', (1.0/5)*LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)**2
print 'LA error: ', (1.0/X_truth.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)**2
print 'LA error:: ', (1.0/5)*LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred, 'fro')**2
print 'LA error: ', LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)**2
print 'LA error: ', LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)
print 'LA error: ', (1.0/X_truth.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)
print 'sklearn MSE error: ', mean_squared_error(X_truth, X_pred)
```

I literally tested every combination I could think of and I still can't have them to match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The formula that's used is a little unusual in that it doesn't take the square root of the sum of squares, whereas `LA.norm` does.

If you look carefully at the docs, you can recreate the formula

`np.sum((X_truth-X_pred)**2)/X_truth.size`

gives 0.49 just like

`mean_squared_error(X_truth, X_pred)`

or

`LA.norm(X_truth - X_pred)**2/X_truth.size`

Comment: your last formula does not give me 0.49. The one I want is the one without the square root. Just the mean squared error (MSE). np.sum((X_truth-X_pred)**2)/len(X_truth) also gives me 2.94 instead of 0.49. Im still confused.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had flattened the matrix for myself before posting the answer, and forgot that I was still using `len`. Edited now.